# Excel not displaying Spanish accents

Tags: excel, mongodb, csv, utf-8, mongoexport

I'm having a bad time exporting data to a CSV file with MongoExport, this data have some Spanish accents that are displaying bad in Excel.

In example, if there's an user called `Raúl` in Excel it appears as `RaÃºl`.

I'm using this script for my export:

```
mongoexport --host my_host --db test --collection users --csv --fields name --out users.csv
```

I read about this error and I found that adding an **UTF-8 BOM** will make the trick, is there any way to tell mongoexport that I'm trying to export an CSV UTF8 BOM file?

**PS:** Just to clarify things, Excel is the only editor that I have problem with. Google Sheets displays those characters perfectly; but I must be able to open it with Excel due to business regulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're on Linux/OS X, using Bash:

Create an empty file with a UTF-8 BOM, then append the output of `mongoexport` to it:

```
$ printf '\xFF\xFE' > users.csv
$ mongoexport --host my_host --db test --collection users --csv --fields name >> users.csv
```

or:

After running `mongoexport` as you are already, use the following command to insert a UTF-8 BOM at the start of the file:

```
sed -i '1s/^/\xef\xbb\xbf/' users.csv
```